# Authentication "cannot fetch"

Tags: javascript, authentication, admin-on-rest

So im trying to implement [this Auth API](https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedReduxCode/tree/master/auth/server) with admin-on-rest. I've tried to follow the auth guide, but get stuck when I come to "Sending Credentials to the REST API". I can see the incoming request in the terminal, but I get "cannot fetch" when i try to login.

My authClient.js looks like this:

```js
import { AUTH_LOGIN } from 'admin-on-rest';

export default (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        const { email, password } = params;
        const request = new Request('http://localhost:3090/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        })
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            });
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

In what way would i need to change the Auth API to make this work?

Comment: `response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300` can be simplified as `response.ok`

Comment: Is the browser logging any error message in the devtools console? If so, you probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45907628/edit to edit/update your question and paste in the exact error message you’re seeing